# Using one text file to search through another text file

Tags: java, while-loop, java.util.scanner

So I've been trying to get this to work for some time. Let me preface this by saying that I'm not a programmer. It's more a of a hobby that I've recently taken up. I've been trying to get 2 text files to search through each other line by line. i.e. One has a bunch of words (around 10, one per line), and the other has many more (close to 500) also one per line. What I would like is for my program to say how many times each of the words in the smaller text file appears in the larger one. What i have so far is:

```
   import java.util.Scanner;  
   import java.io.File;  
   import java.util.regex.Pattern;  

   public class StringSearch 
   {  

   public static void main (String args[]) throws java.io.IOException
       {  
   int tot = 0;  
   Scanner scan = null;  
   Scanner scan2 = null;
   String str = null;
   String str2 = null;


   File file = new File("C:\\sample2.txt");
   File file2 = new File("C:\\sample3.txt");
   scan = new Scanner(file); 
   scan2 = new Scanner(file2);
      while (scan.hasNextLine()) 
      {
        str = scan.nextLine();
        tot = 0;
            while (scan2.hasNextLine())
            {
                str2 = scan2.nextLine();
                    if(str.equals(str2)) 
                    {
                 tot++;
                     }
             }
   System.out.println("The String = " + str + " and it occurred " + tot + " times");
        }

   }
   }
```

Not sure why this isnt working. It reads the first word in the first text file fine and counts how many times it appears in the second one, but then it just stop and doesnt move on the the second word in the first file. I hope that makes sense. Something is wrong with the second while loop I think, but I have no idea what.

So, any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm hoping to get this to work and move on to more complicated projects in the future. Gotta start somewhere right?

Cheers Guys

Comment: If you load all the words of the first file into an array, all you need to do is read from the second file and compare it to the contents of the array. The amount of words is small enough that it won't take much memory, and you are only dealing with one file.

Comment: note, by using shell: `fgrep -f sample2.txt sample3.txt`

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are running across is that you are using a scanner within a scanner. The way that you currently have your scanners nested, it causes one scanner to completely read through its entire text file for the first word, but after that first run through, it has already read the entire file and will never return true for `scan2.hasNextLine()`.

A better way to achieve what you want is what remyabel stated. You should create an array that will contain all of the words from your small file that will be iterated through every time you go through a word in your other file. You would also need to create something to keep track of how many times each word is hit so you could use something like a hashmap.

It would look something along the lines of this:

```
Scanner scan = null;  
Scanner scan2 = null;
String str = null;
String str2 = null;


File file = new File("C:\\sample2.txt");
File file2 = new File("C:\\sample3.txt");
scan = new Scanner(file); 
scan2 = new Scanner(file2);
//Will contain all of your words to check against
ArrayList<String> dictionary = new ArrayList<String>();
//Contains the number of times each word is hit
HashMap<String,Integer> hits = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
while(scan.hasNextLine())
{
    str = scan.nextLine();
    dictionary.add(str);
    hits.put(str, 0);
}
  while (scan2.hasNextLine())
      {
          str2 = scan2.nextLine();
          for(String str: dictionary)
             {
              if(str.equals(str2)) 
                {
                   hits.put(str, hits.get(str) + 1);
                }
             }
      }
  for(String str: dictionary)
    {
       System.out.println("The String = " + str + " and it occurred " + hits.get(str) + " times");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a buffered reader and read the file into a map of `<String, Integer>`:

```
String filename = args[0];
BufferedReader words = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(FILENAME));
Map<String, Integer>m = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
for(String word: words.readLine()){
    if(word!=null && word.trim().length()>0) {
        m.add(String, 0);
    }
}
```

Then read the words list and increment the map's value each time you find one:

```
String filename = args[1];
BufferedReader listOfWords = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(FILENAME2));
for(String word: listOfWords.readLine()){
    if(word!=null && word.trim().length()>0) {
        if(m.get(word)!=null){
            m.add(word, m.get(word) + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Then print the results:

```
for(String word: map.keys()){
     if(map.get(word)>0){
         System.out.println("The String = " + word + " occurred " + map.get(word) + " times");
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach with using nested loops would scan the second file for every word in the first one. This would be highly inefficient. I suggest loading the first file in a `HashMap`.

Not only this would leverage on quick lookups, you could update the count of occurrence easily as well. Not to mention, you would be scanning the second file just once and any duplicates that you might have in the first one would automatically be ignored (as the results would be the same).

```
Map<String, Integer> wordCounts = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

Scanner scanner = new Scanner("one\nfive\nten");
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    wordCounts.put(scanner.nextLine(), 0);
}
scanner.close();

scanner = new Scanner("one\n" + // 1 time
                      "two\nthree\nfour\n" +
                      "five\nfive\n" + // 2 times
                      "six\nseven\neight\nnine\n" +
                      "ten\nten\nten"); // 3 times

while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    String word = scanner.nextLine();
    Integer integer = wordCounts.get(word);
    if (integer != null) {
        wordCounts.put(word, ++integer);
    }
}
scanner.close();

for (String word : wordCounts.keySet()) {
    int count = wordCounts.get(word);
    if (count > 0) {
        System.out.println("'" + word + "' occurs " + count + " times.");
    }
}
```

***Output** :*

```
'ten' occurs 3 times.
'five' occurs 2 times.
'one' occurs 1 times.
```

Answer (score 0):

Its just a simple logic issue..

add following statement below System.out.println

scan2 = new Scanner(file2);

Comment: How does this address the OP's question ?